# Combine the result of two select queries into one table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following two tables:

STOCK_ON_HAND: This is showing me all of the stock that I have on hand
STOCK_ON_ORDER: This is showing me all of the stock that I have on order

I have the following two queries to summarise the tables:

```
SELECT STOCK_CODE, SUM(QTY)
FROM STOCK_ON_HAND
GROUP BY STOCK_CODE
HAVING SUM(QTY) <>0;
```

And

```
SELECT STOCK_CODE, SUM(ON_ORDER)
FROM STOCK_ON_ORDER
GROUP BY STOCK_CODE
HAVING SUM(STOCK_ON_ORDER) <>0;
```

I basically want to combine the above with into one table showing the following fields:

- STOCK_CODE
- STOCK_ON_HAND
- STOCK_ON_ORDER

What would the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: Thank you, my question did not take into consideration all the variables. Will post a new question with all the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` which Access does not support directly, but you can simulate it with `UNION` like this:

```
SELECT h.STOCK_CODE, h.HQTY AS STOCK_ON_HAND, o.OQTY AS STOCK_ON_ORDER
FROM (
  SELECT STOCK_CODE, SUM(QTY) AS HQTY
  FROM STOCK_ON_HAND
  GROUP BY STOCK_CODE
  HAVING SUM(QTY) <> 0
) h LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT STOCK_CODE, SUM(ON_ORDER) AS OQTY
  FROM STOCK_ON_ORDER
  GROUP BY STOCK_CODE
  HAVING SUM(ON_ORDER) <> 0
) o ON o.STOCK_CODE = h.STOCK_CODE
UNION
SELECT o.STOCK_CODE, h.HQTY AS STOCK_ON_HAND, o.OQTY AS STOCK_ON_ORDER
FROM (
  SELECT STOCK_CODE, SUM(QTY) AS HQTY
  FROM STOCK_ON_HAND
  GROUP BY STOCK_CODE
  HAVING SUM(QTY) <> 0
) h RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT STOCK_CODE, SUM(ON_ORDER) AS OQTY
  FROM STOCK_ON_ORDER
  GROUP BY STOCK_CODE
  HAVING SUM(ON_ORDER) <> 0
) o ON o.STOCK_CODE = h.STOCK_CODE
```

If you don't want to see `null`s in the results (if they exist) but replace them with `0`s, use the function [`Nz()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c), like this:

```
SELECT h.STOCK_CODE, Nz(h.HQTY, 0) AS STOCK_ON_HAND, Nz(o.HQTY, 0) AS STOCK_ON_ORDER
```

Or get the distinct `STOCK_CODE`s from both tables and `LEFT JOIN` them to each of the tables:

```
SELECT c.STOCK_CODE, h.HQTY AS STOCK_ON_HAND, o.OQTY AS STOCK_ON_ORDER
FROM ((
  SELECT STOCK_CODE FROM STOCK_ON_HAND
  UNION
  SELECT STOCK_CODE FROM STOCK_ON_ORDER
) AS c LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT STOCK_CODE, SUM(QTY) AS HQTY
  FROM STOCK_ON_HAND
  GROUP BY STOCK_CODE
  HAVING SUM(QTY) <> 0
) h ON h.STOCK_CODE = c.STOCK_CODE )
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT STOCK_CODE, SUM(ON_ORDER) AS OQTY
  FROM STOCK_ON_ORDER
  GROUP BY STOCK_CODE
  HAVING SUM(ON_ORDER) <> 0
) o ON o.STOCK_CODE = c.STOCK_CODE
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing a `UNION ALL` before aggregating:

```
SELECT STOCK_CODE, SUM(on_hand), SUM(on_order)
FROM (SELECT STOCK_CODE, SUM(QTY) as on_hand, 0 on_order
      FROM STOCK_ON_HAND
      GROUP BY STOCK_CODE
      UNION ALL
      SELECT STOCK_CODE, 0, SUM(ON_ORDER) as on_order
      FROM STOCK_ON_ORDER
      GROUP BY STOCK_CODE
     ) s
GROUP BY STOCK_CODE
HAVING on_hand <> 0 OR on_order <> 0;
```

If MS Access does not support `UNION ALL` in the `FROM` clause, you can use a view to set that up.

Comment: Thank you. I realised that I oversimplified the question and as there are a couple of variables that I did not take into consideration. While the above works, it does not give me the answer I need. Will post a new question. Thank you for your help

Comment: @gdekoker . . . The columns were not quite right in the subqueries.  Each subqueries should have three columns, rather than two.